# D3D12 Dynamic indexing of textures with different formats

Tags: hlsl, pixel-shader, directx-12, direct3d12

In shader model 5.1 we can use dynamic indexing for textures like so:

```
Texture2D textures[5] : register(t0)
PixelShader(Input p) : SV_TARGET
{
     float4 color = textures[0].Sample(someSampler, p.UV);
     return color;
}
```

Here it's assumed that all textures have 4 channels (rgba). However, I have no idea how to sample when my texture array is a mix of different formats like BC3 (rgba), BC4 (single channel R), BC5 (dual channel RG). For example, in case of BC4 I could try

```
float R = textures[0].Sample(someSampler, p.UV).r;
```

But wouldn't this just skip over three texels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSLS Shader model 5.1 is quite confusing because you have a distinction between "texture array" and "texture array"...

The first meaning is the one that appeared with DX10, A single texture resource is made of several slices and a shader can index in the slices. The major limitation is that each slice have to share size and format.

The second meaning, introduced with API like DX12 or Vulkan is closer to "an array of textures". You can now group multiple resource objects into an array of descriptors. The shader can freely use any of them with dynamic indexing. The constraint of a texture array are lifted. The one limitation is the use of the `NonUniformIndex` intrinsic to let the driver fix up indexing limitation a GPU may have.

As for your original questionm, It is then up to you to know what texture are where, if you group texture with formats like BC4 and BC7, it is probably because one is an albedo while the other may be a gloss map. Your shader will give the semantic to what it read. But if you want a BC4 texture to expand as `RRRR` instead of the default `R001`, you can use the component mapping in the shader resource view.

Comment: Speaking about component mapping,I'm curious why is it not in DirectX11 as well? :) This is so useful to have it at pipeline level instead of  "yet another define" in shaders?

Comment: Because they probably assumed it was not common enough on the GPUs at the time, or a mere forgotten thing… PS3 and X360 both were able to do it already, so it is not a new. As of today, `DXGI` is not yet as flexible as it should too, for example, most hardware support `SNORM` on `1010102` while `DXGI_FORMAT` only have the `UNORM` flavor. This is because formats are not just a simple enumeration for the hardware but construct from properties.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a 'texture array'. This is just a way to declare 5 textures bound individually, and the syntax lets you use indices to select `t0` through `t1`. A 'texture array' is declared as follows:

```
Texture2DArray textures : register(t0);
```

Every texture in the texture array must be the same format (it's a single resource), and you use a `float3` to index it for sampling.

```
float4 color = textures.Sample(someSampler, float3(p.UV,0) );
```

What you are doing above is basically the same thing as:

```
Texture2D texture0 : register(t0);
Texture2D texture1 : register(t1);
Texture2D texture2 : register(t2);
Texture2D texture3 : register(t3);
Texture2D texture4 : register(t4);
```

As such, the formats of each texture are completely independent, the code here:

```
float R = textures[0].Sample(someSampler, p.UV).r;
```

This just samples the texture in `t0` as normal, returning just the red channel. For a BC4, this will cause the hardware to decompress the correct 4x4 block (or blocks depending on the UV and sampler mode), and return the red channel from the reconstruction.

> If you are new to DirectX and HLSL, I strongly recommend *not* using DirectX 12 to start. It's a fairly unforgiving API designed for graphics experts, so you should consider starting with DirectX 11 instead. The APIs both drive the same hardware, they just do it with different programmer abstractions. DirectX 12 documentation also generally assumes you are already an expert with DirectX 11 anyhow and the HLSL usage is basically the same (with the addition of programmatic control over root signatures). See *DirectX Tool Kit* for [DirectX 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) and [DirectX 12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started).